# Import Module TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, typeerror, nonetype

so I'm trying to install a module and am having some issues importing it. As far as I know, I have it installed via pip correctly up to this point, as the moduel shows up correctly under `pip freeze`. I'm obviously a relative noob, but [here's the link](https://github.com/derek-adair/nflgame) to the module I'm trying to work with.

I don't believe this is an issue with the module itself, rather my inexperience of setting up module with Python. Thanks in advance for any advice!

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import nflgame
Updating (None, 'PRE', None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import nflgame
  File "C:\Users\plindquist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nflgame\__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
    import nflgame.game  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\plindquist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nflgame\game.py", line 15, in <module>
    import nflgame.sched
  File "C:\Users\plindquist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nflgame\sched.py", line 98, in <module>
    games, last_updated = _create_schedule()
  File "C:\Users\plindquist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nflgame\sched.py", line 87, in _create_schedule
    week_was_updated = nflgame.update_sched.update_week(sched, year, phase, week)
  File "C:\Users\plindquist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nflgame\update_sched.py", line 134, in update_week
    games = week_schedule(year, stype, week)
  File "C:\Users\plindquist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nflgame\update_sched.py", line 55, in week_schedule
    url = schedule_url(year, stype, week)
  File "C:\Users\plindquist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nflgame\update_sched.py", line 45, in schedule_url
    return '%sseason=%d&seasonType=%s&week=%d' % (xmlurl, year, stype, week)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

Comment: Have you tried filing an issue on the github repo about this? Also looking at https://github.com/derek-adair/nflgame/blob/master/README.md , there seems to be more steps to run after `pip install`. Have you ran those?

Comment: Hi Devesh, thanks for the response. Yes I've read through that page as well as the [tutorial for non programmers](https://github.com/derek-adair/nflgame/wiki/Tutorial-for-non-programmers:-Installation-and-examples), the only thing that I have not specifically done is create a virtual environment using venv, but I did not think that was necessary as it is listed as optional.

Comment: Okay, in that case, you can raise an issue with their repo about your error.

Answer (score 0):

`nflgame` is trying to access http://www.nfl.com/feeds-rs/currentWeek.json, which at this time, 6/19/2020 is currently a 404 error. Because it can't access the json data, `week` and `year` never get set and the script crashes later when trying to use the variables.